# Count from latest timestamps only

Tags: sqlite, count, timestamp

I'm trying to count latest actions from devices in my table:

| device | action | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | running | 2022-09-12 16:20:10 |
| 1 | shutdown | 2022-09-10 16:20:10 |
| 2 | running | 2022-09-12 16:20:10 |
| 2 | starting | 2022-09-11 16:20:10 |
| 3 | starting | 2022-09-11 16:20:10 |

I'm trying :

```
SELECT
    count(device)
FROM
    table
WHERE
    action='shutdown'
    AND
    timestamp=(SELECT max(timestamp) FROM table)
;
```

But can't get it to work. Expected result :

- when querying `shutdown`: 0
- when querying `running`: 2
- when querying `starting`: 1

All I get is the full count of the actions.

Comment: Show expected output

Comment: Expected output for querying shutdown counts in query: 0
Expected output for querying running counts in query: 2
Expected output for querying starting counts in query: 1

Comment: Why shutdown is 0? There is a shutdown line in your data.

Comment: Because It's not the latest timestamp for that device

Comment: You need to provide a coherent explanation of what you are trying to achieve and provide representative data and desired output. Right now I have no clue what you want.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I'll try... I need to count (or sum)  only the selected action with the latest timestamps. For example: Count the number of times the action Shutdown appears in all devices, only for the latest timestamps.
So the device 1 has two timestamps. I need the latest only. So If i want to count the number of times the action Shutdown appears in the latest timestamps of all devices, i get a zero (0). If i need to count the number of times the action running appears, i'll get a 2. There are only two times the action Running appears in the latest timestamps for all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a key based on
concatenating 2 columns (device and time stamp when the timestamp is max)

see the code below:

```
select count(*) from diario where device || timestamp in (select device || mx from(select device,max(timestamp) mx from diario group by device)) and action = "shutdown";
```

the result is 0 when action is shutdown, 2 running, 1 starting

Answer (score 1):

If you want results for all `action`s then you can do a LEFT join of the distinct `action`s to a query that returns the last timestamp for each device and aggregate:

```
SELECT a.action, COUNT(t.action) count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT action FROM tablename) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT action, MAX(timestamp) FROM tablename GROUP BY device) t
ON t.action = a.action
GROUP BY a.action;
```

Results:

| action | count |
| --- | --- |
| running | 2 |
| shutdown | 0 |
| starting | 1 |

If you want results for only one type of `action`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(action = ?) OVER () count
FROM tablename
GROUP BY device
HAVING MAX(timestamp);
```

Replace `?` with the `action` that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SKFhvHIa).